# arduino compiler (Using Java and Spring boot)

Tags: arduino

Pass the arunino code from the web client to the server. The server then tries to send the web client back to the result of compiling it using the arduino compiler.

Is there a more efficient alternative to running the Arduino Builder exe from the command line on the server and getting the results?
(Using Java and Spring boot)

How does the compiler work in the Arduino editor?
(https://create.arduino.cc/editor)

Comment: explaining how a compiler works might be a bit to much for this format. if you are interested in how compilers work I suggest you get yourself some literature or search the web for resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make a compilation server, you could try [using a arduino-makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile), ([here](http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/compiling-arduino-sketches-using-makefile) is more of an explanation how to use it)on the server side and run it from java or whatever you are using, capture the output and send it back to the client.

EDIT: Taken from the arduino-makefile description: Makefile for Arduino sketches. It defines the workflows for compiling code, flashing it to Arduino and even communicating through Serial.

If you want to replicate Arduino Editor, you would either need to use their browser plugin or write your own to download the compiled binary code into the clients Arduino.